# Unable to Install WebSphere Developer Tools (WDT)

Tags: websphere-liberty, ibm-wdt

I've downloaded https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/pot/LibertyPoT_17.0.0.1_WIN.zip but I'm stuck at step 1 of section "0.5 Install WebSphere Developer Tools (WDT)" in setup.pdf where I see

[image: this error message]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check paragraph at `0.3 Installing Liberty and the Java Runtime` and its note:

> To install for windows or linux,
>
> a. Liberty is already installed for you {LAB_HOME)/wlp
>
> b. The IBM JRE is already installed for you
>   {LAB_HOME)/wlp/java [...]
>
> c. The IBM_JRE is set to default Java in
>   the {LAB_HOME)/wlp/etc/server.env
>
> If you want to override this for a specific server create a server.env
>   file in the   usr/servers/ directory.
>
> *Note: If JAVA_HOME is already set in your shell, then you will need to “unset JAVA_HOME”. To check, execute “env| grep –i java_home”. If
>   it returns with a value, then execute “unset JAVA_HOME”

Then remind that Eclipse looks for jre/jdk based on `vm` parameter in `eclipse.ini`.
In the zip file downloaded it should be

```
-vm ..\wlp\java\bin\javaw.exe
```

It should be correct, anyway you could try setting an absolute path so you are sure it doesn't care about working directory.

Comment: ¡Hola @gile! Does Windows understand ".."? Anyhow, prior to posting this question I've fiddled with multiple variants of the -vm switch to no avail. -vm C:\wlp_pot\WLP_17.0.0.1\wlp\java\bin\javaw.exe and -vm "C:\wlp_pot\WLP_17.0.0.1\wlp\java\bin\javaw.exe" both did not work and give some variant of the initial error. It seems like some variant of https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=102239 perhaps?

Comment: Yes, Windows understands .. Are you sure the PATH environment variable does not get wrong java path? Did you check both {LAB_HOME)/wlp/etc/server.env and {LAB_HOME)/usr/servers/server.env ?